# KeyError: 20, not sure what is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I am new to python and am currently trying to create a program that will create a list of yearly percentage changes in revenue.

This is what I have so far:

```
revs = {}    
for year in range(14, 20):    
    revs[year] = float(input("Revenue in {0}: ".format(year)))

revs_change = []
for year in range(14, 20):
    next_year = year + 1
    revs_change.append((revs[next_year] - revs[year])/revs[year])

print(revs_change[0])
```

The error comes on the 8th line and it has something to do with using the variable next_year.

Thanks!

Comment: You write keys 14 through 19, and then you try to read keys 14 through 20.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to print out the values of `year` and `next_year` the problem is that there is no value for `revs[next_year=20]`.

One way is to do like this-

```
start = 14
end   = 21
for year in range(start, end):
     revs[year] = float(input("Revenue in {0}: ".format(year)))

revs_change = []
for year in range(start, end-1):
    next_year = year + 1
    print(f"Year: {year}, Next Year: {next_year}\n")
    revs_change.append( (revs[next_year] - revs[year])/revs[year] )

print(revs_change[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the function of that print line when you're creating the list? Is that just to check that the correct years were inputted?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the end limit for any range you give will be taken excluding that upper limit i.e if you set the upper limit as 20, it evaluates up to 19. Give the upper limit as 21 so that you'll get the desired output